# How to make Navigator function in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a this Widget [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hElJZ.png)
and this call:

```
    void navigateToDetail() {
       var context;
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
         return const NoteDetail();
      }));
    }
```

It is nothing happen when I click on Floating Action Button, I've tried to write the FAB without the function and it works normally but with this function I can't navigate.
I wanna this function working..

Comment: Remove the `var context;` and always post your code in text format, no code images.

Comment: I am remove var context; then I am running th e code, the result is undefine name context. dart(undefined identifer). How to correct this error ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that your function was out of statefull, pass the context by parameter in the function, I changed the answer, see how it turned out. Another detail, better would be if your function was inside the statefull, I created a mixin.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a StatefulWidget, there is no need to pass the context to the function, just call the navigator.

```
void navigateToDetail(BuildContext context) {
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
     return const NoteDetail();
  }));
}
```